# How to build a .jar file from a WSDL?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, wsdl2java

I have a wsdl and one of the methods requires an "arrayofstring" which is done I believe by creating a new instance of the ArrayOString.class (which is created using wsdl2java)

So far I downloaded the codegen plug in to eclipse and created the classes, but from here I don't know what to do to be able to use it in my project in which I need to create the arrayofstring instance

Hopefully, that makes sense. If not leave a comment and I'll try to make it clearer. Thanks!

Comment: wsimport creates a set of files you need to add to your project.

Comment: Have a look at https://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/wsimport-mojo.html